# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin can't install nuget package MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache plugin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Visual Studio 2017. I try to create application using mvvm cross. I sucessfully added mvvm cross library, but when I try to install MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache package I got this:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` your application must target Android 7.0 or higher.

To fix this:

- In Visual Studio:

  1. Right Click project > Properties > Application
  2. Set Target to 7.0 or higher, a good idea is also to Compile using Latest Platform
- In Xamarin Studio:

  1. Right Click project > Options > Android Application
  2. Set Target to 7.0 or higher, a good idea is also to Compile using Latest Platform

Comment: When you installed VS 2017 it installs only Android API 6.0 by default. I installed Android API 7.0 and that's solve my issue.